# What is the difference between RUN and CMD in a Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

I am going to change my permission of files to `600`. The following command works perfectly.

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config'
```

But this one failed

```
CMD /bin/bash -c 'chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config'
```

In the beginning, I thought the shell environment isn't `bash` so caused the error. However, adding `bin/bash` didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Don’t confuse RUN with CMD. RUN actually runs a command and commits the result; CMD does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.

[reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: `RUN` performs the step during the image build, `CMD` is the default command when you start a container. If you define `CMD` and then start your container with a different command (e.g. `docker run $my_image /bin/bash`), you'll never see it run since you replaced your `chmod` command with an empty `/bin/bash` command.

---

The detailed explanation:

The **`RUN`** command creates a temporary container based off of the previous step of the build, executes your selected command, and when the command returns it captures the filesystem changes as a new layer of your image. Run is the equivalent of doing a `docker run` + `docker commit` to generate your image, but with a reproducible process.

The **`CMD`** command replaces the current value of the image metadata for the `command` value that you can see when you inspect the image. You can only have one value for `CMD` for your image. You can also easily override the value of the image command by passing any string after the image name, e.g. `docker run busybox echo hello` replaces the default `/bin/sh` command with an `echo hello` command for that specific container.

There's also **`ENTRYPOINT`** which defines the entrypoint for your image. When you define an entrypoint, any value for `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the entrypoint when starting your container (a container is only started with a single process as pid 1 and exits when that process exits).

---

**Shell vs Exec syntax:** Note that each of these accepts a command to run in two forms, the shell/string form, and the exec/json form. The shell form is anything that isn't a json list, and the result command is run as `/bin/sh -c "$your_string_here"`. A shell is useful for IO redirection, chaining commands, and variable expansion. But a shell will also intercept signals which can cause issues when the container is stopped. The exec form runs your command directly in the OS without a shell, which is better for signals, but lacking all the other shell features. When you chain an entrypoint and cmd together, you almost always want the exec syntax since `/bin/sh -c` only accepts one argument. It's common to run a shell script but have the last command run be an `exec` which replaces the shell. E.g. a common entrypoint structure is:

Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["server", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... steps to setup the host, make configs, fix permissions, copy files, etc ...
# ...
# now run the value of CMD, replacing this shell as pid 1:
exec "$@"
```